# How to create Input dialog box in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I want to create input dialog box in matlab. I am performing simple addition operation in MATLAB. 
Two variables name, a and b are needed to be given by user and then performing addition c=a+b; and display it in output. Both a and b should be positive integer only. 
I tried following:

```
    a = inputdlg({'Enter positive integer (a)'});     
    b = inputdlg({'Enter positive integer (b)'});        
    c=a+b;
```

But it is giving following error:

> Undefined function or method 'plus' for input arguments of type
>   'cell'.

Please suggest how can i code the above program in described way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the output of `inputdlg` is a cell array containing a string; here a 1-cell array.

Hence you need to access the content of the cell array to perform the operation; for example using {curly brackets} : `{a}` and `{b}`.

In your case, since you are asking the use for a number, you need to convert the output, which is a string, to an actual number Matlab can use using for instance `str2double`, which operates on cell arrays

```
c = str2double(a) + str2double(b)
```